# C# Uri class - stripping off a port number from Authority

Tags: c#, class, uri

I'm trying tu use System.Uri to strip off various information.

E.g. it gets me Uri.Authority.

When my URI is  http://some.domain:52146/something, Uri.Authority.ToString() gives me "some.domain:52146".

I'd rather have "some.domain" and the port with a separate call.

Any ideas whow I could strip off the :port_number stuff most elegantly, either with a Uri-method I don't know of or with some string manipulation?

And getting back the http:// would also be useful (to know for example whether it's http or https).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Uri.Host` and `Uri.Port`:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://some.domain:52146/something");
string host = uri.Host;  // some.domain
int port = uri.Port;     // 52146
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I learnt about the properties `Uri.Host` and `Uri.Port` now I know that `Uri.Scheme` gives me the protocol.